# Simple solution for using same tensorflow code in Browser or NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow

I wrote some Tensorflow code. The files look like

1. For Node

```js
import something from "@tensorflow/tfjs-node"

export function run(){/*...*/}
```

2. For browser

```js
import something from "@tensorflow/tfjs"

export function run(){/*...*/}
```

Is there any way I could just have one file to avoid repeating the function `run()`?

I asked ChatGPT but the answer does not seem correct to me (extract `run` into `common.js` and `import` it to each file).